# jquery datatable not getting auto reload after sorting, changing row selection limit, or after using global search

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am implementing sorting (Order by) for dataTable at server side. All sessms to be fine Even my data gets properly sorted (I can check that in firebug.). Now the problem is , datatable is not getting reloaded after that, and "processing..." continues to appear. Any clue on where to write function for reload. I know it can be done by

```
 oTable.fnDraw(true);
```

but I dont know where to write it after header is clicked for sorting. Let me know if you need any code snippet to debug.

Edit1**

I am not able to reload table even after using global search, or changing no. of rows to display. Any idea why this is happening???

```
var oTable = $('#datatable').dataTable( {
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "datatableprocessor",
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                 "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) { return nRow; },
                "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, rfrshCallbk ) {
                    $('.search').each(function(index) {
                        var name =  $(this).attr("name");
                        var tempName = name.replace("search","condition" );
                        var condition = $("[name='"+tempName+"']").val();
                        var value = $(this).val();
                        aoData.push({ "name": name, "value": value+""+condition });
                    });
                    aoData.push({ "name": "queryId", "value": "test" });
                    $.ajax( {
                            "dataType": 'json',
                            "type": "POST",
                            "url": sSource,
                            "data": aoData,
                            "success": rfrshCallbk

                    } );
                },
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                  { "sName": "c.id", "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
                  { "sName": "c.firstname", "aTargets": [ 1 ] },
                  { "sName": "c.lastname", "aTargets": [ 2 ] },
                  { "sName": "c.telephone", "aTargets": [ 3 ] }

                ]


            } );//
```

Edit 2 -----
I tried to check if the Json comming is correct, so to debug I changed code to

```
 "success": function(json){
        alert(JSON.stringify(json));
                    rfrshCallbk(json);
 }
```

In both cases , when I reload my page or do sorting json string is same .. ??!!?? don't know what is wrong ??!!??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution,  I havent implemented ""sEcho and was every time sending back "sEcho" as "1", that was warding me from getting a refreshed list.

Answer (score 0):

To reload the dataTable data we use

```
oTable.fnDraw();
```

not 
     oTable.fnDraw(true);
,be written where you are performing click event.

Comment: thanks!! but I don't perform any click even't it is fired automatically by dataTable, and through firebug I can see the ajax returning correct result.

Comment: any Idea on how I can pull the response from ajax and perform re-draw ??

Comment: @Vyas,ok i got you if your datatable is performing Sorting,Searching operation it might not to reload again.                                        Here is my code that i had initialized.  var oTable = $('#DataTable').dataTable({
           "bServerSide": true,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
                
                return nRow;
            },
            "aoColumns": [{ /* column you have mentioned      */ }

                     ]});here i didn't mention any reload and its working

Comment: Here i missed the url,   "sAjaxSource":"/* your server url */",

Comment: strangely their isn't any much difference in my code, can you please check edited post

Comment: Please Try this line.. after using your code on success         rfrshCallbk(json); oTable.fnDraw();